# How to eval a member function name to a function object?

Tags: python, eval

I have define some functions in a class A

and also in the class A, I have a function to call the other function by their name

But When I use `eval('funcname')`, it says the function is `not defined`

How can I eval a member function name to be a function object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely clear from your question, but it sounds like you're asking how to call one method in a class by name from another method within that class.

Since all instance methods have the `self` parameter, you can simply look up the method you want on that via `getattr`:

```
def call_by_name(self, method_name):
    method = getattr(self, method_name)
    method()
```

Comment: But it says "AttributeError: XXX instance has no attribute 'xxx'"

Comment: So, does it have that attribute? Show a real example.

Comment: I fount the reason is that the function to be called is a private function, but I don't know why?

Comment: @TankyWoo We are purposely trying to avoid having you use `eval` because it is highly dangerous

Comment: @jamylak Thank you, I will replace `eval` with `getattr`

Answer (score 0):

Following works, but why would you want to do that?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fa(self):
        print('Hello')
    def fb(self):
#        self.fa()
        eval('self.fa()')

a = A()
a.fb()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is useful,

If you want to call a instance method here is the way

```
class A:
def foo(self):
         print " ok"
         return "ok"
 def bar(self):
         #i = A()
         #print eval('i.foo()')
          print eval('self.foo()')
 a = A()
 a.bar()
```

The methods are the instance attributes not the class attributes so we have to call the 
methods through instance only.